# Non-negative integer data type in java

Tags: java, integer

Modulo-2 have a CARDINAL type which can hold any whole number from 0 to 65535 in a 16-bit microcomputer. Is there any data type in java that closely resembles CARDINAL? I know custom data type can be created in java for this purpose.

I have heard that there is going to be unsigned integer arithmetic API in java 8. But I want to know if there exists one before java 8.

Answer (score 3):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Read about primitive data types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: But beware, using `char` as a numeric type may violate the principle of least surprise.  For example, String concatenation will treat a `char` operand differently than an `int` operand, possibly leading to unexpected behavior.